# L1: mixed animals + L2: mixed animals = L3: rabbits (only)

Tags: r, merge, compare, diff

Have two lists, L1 and L2, of thousands of lines separated by hard returns.

There are lines in L1 that are not present in L2 and are useless for this job.

There are common (duplicated) lines in L1 and L2 that are also useless and should be eliminated.

There are lines in L2 that are not included in L1: these are the request.

Tried to merge, compare diff but the output got mixed.

L1:
D
C

L2:
C
R

L3:
R

Answer (score 0):

look at the setdiff command:

```
L1= c("D","C")
L2= c("C","R")
L3 = setdiff(L2,L1)
```

Comment: I used

Diff L1 L2

As I am could not use exactly the instructions coming in the replies the output was five times bigger with thousands of duplicates and intermissions (---)

The letters  "D,C,R" are not real. I tried to use them as an example... 

(C ats and D ogs are both in L1 and L2; but R abbits only in L2. And words not present in L1 are the target(

Could you please help me again in the solution?

Comment: Did you use setdiff(L2,L1) and not setdiff(L1,L2) ? Also if you have duplicates in L2 that are not in L1 and want to remove them: `unique(setdiff(L2,L1))` with the answer underneath: `unique(L2[!L2 %in% L1])`

Comment: The line is:

setdiff(L1.txt,L2.txt)


:-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `L1.txt,L2.txt'

Comment: You are typing this at the command prompt... To start R just type 'R' at the prompt (if it does not exist you can install it from www.r-project.org). You really should have a look at an introduction to R. Once you get to the R console type in the following: `L1=scan("L1.txt",what=character()); L2=scan("L2.txt",what=character()); L3=setdiff(L2,L1); print(L3)`

Comment: 'R' is not installed here and I will download. I was lost in terminal! Thanks for your time, patience and advice. Let me share the results in the future.

Comment: H. Roggeman, absolutely perfect and marvellous your instruction. In milliseconds thousands of registers were done. Print L3 is the output but implicit, I suspect, as not L3 file is generated or if already and previously created is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

You could also index L2 with `%in%` using a not (`!`) before:

```
L1= c("D","C")
L2= c("C","R")
L2[!L2 %in% L1]

#[1] "R"
```